# Unable to create a foreign key in Laravel migrations

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-jetstream

I am trying to create a foreign key relation in user table with user_role table.

**user table migration**

user_role column is a foreign key column

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->string('user_role')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_role')->references('role')->on("user_role")->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
            $table->text('profile_photo_path')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**user_role table**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create("user_role",function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string("role")->nullable();
        });
    }
```

migrations are not applying following error is generating

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `ecommerce`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed") (SQL: alter table `users` add constraint `users_user_role_foreign` foreign key (`user_role`) references `user_role` (`role`) on delete cascade)

  at F:\ecommerce-indian\ecommerce\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:678
    674▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    675▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    676▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    677▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 678▕             throw new QueryException(
    679▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    680▕             );
    681▕         }
    682▕

  1   F:\ecommerce-indian\ecommerce\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:471
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1005 Can't create table `ecommerce`.`users` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")")      

  2   F:\ecommerce-indian\ecommerce\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:471
      PDOStatement::execute()
```

what's the problem with foreign key where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: You have to create the foreign key on the primary key of the second table. In your case, add `user_role_id` to users which will refer to `id` in `user_role` table.

Comment: @V-K thanks it worked but is there any way to connect with role column

Comment: yes there is a way. check my reply.

Comment: @ManinderSingh, you do not need to create FK on `role`, because there are the same fields in both tables, and it's just a duplication

Comment: add role as unique

$table->string("role")->unique(); 

that will do it. @ManinderSingh

Answer (score 0):

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_role')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_role')->references('id')->on("user_role")->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
            $table->text('profile_photo_path')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

before create users migration create user_role migration and use field `id` on `user_role`

Comment: what if he want to create 'role' as FK. not ID?

Answer (score 0):

your role must be unique.

```
$table->string("role")->unique();
```

this is the code for users migration

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->foreignId('current_team_id')->nullable();
            $table->text('profile_photo_path')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

then create "user_role" migration with this code.

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create("user_role",function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string("role")->unique();
        });
    }
```

and then create another migration like

```
php artisan make:migration add_user_role_in_users_table
```

in that add this code

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('user_role')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('user_role')->references('role')->on("user_role")->onDelete('cascade');
        });
    }
```

and then run

```
php artisan migrate
```